# How to add server instance of wildfly to netbeans 11.3

Tags: wildfly, netbeans-11

I want to add Wildfly server under "Services > Servers". When I right click on "Servers" and press "Add Server" a window opens. On window "Add Server Instance" I don't see Wildfly.

I am using Apache Netbeans IDE 11.3

**Why doesn't Netbeans offer me Wildfly as an option?**

[image: Step 1] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further investigation I found out that out-of-the-box support for Wildfly was added in Netbeans 12.

I found that info in the release notes for Netbeans 12 ([HERE](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb120/)).

[image: Release notes of Netbeans 12]

Comment: Just to add to your answer: [1] Wildfly used to be supported in NetBeans 8.2, and support was reintroduced with NetBeans 12.x. [2] The reason for the temporary lack of support was not for any technical reasons. There were licensing issues associated with NetBeans migrating to Apache. See [NetBeans issue 2415 Bring back support for WildFly server](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2415) . [3] If you want to use WildFly on NetBeans, use release 12.0 or later. NetBeans 8.2 would also work for earlier releases of Wildfly, but 8.2 is no longer supported.